# Algo parecido a Oracle Service Bus pero de Microsoft

Tags: .net, webservice

Estoy buscando algo como Oracle Service Bus en .net, alguien sabe como se llama como se puede utilizar o en ultimo caso como se lo podría implementar?.

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La que conozco y ademas se integra a Azure es

[NServiceBus](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/)

como veras este trabaja con Queues

[Microsoft Azure Service Bus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/)

Tambien hay otras alternativas como ser

[MassTransit](http://masstransit-project.com/)

Answer (score 1):

La herramienta que buscas se llama [Microsoft Biztalk](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/biztalk). Es su producto de bus de servicios empresarial.